# Having problem with changing Hibernate configuration at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I have developed a Java standalone application for Hibernate & H2 database testing purposes. This application works simply; First, it configures a database connection on the current machine disk space (Using the H2 URL-Only feature), then it closes the current session factory and tries to initialize a new configuration to a new H2 database. Everything is good, but after switching to the new database when a query is sent to the Hibernate this error will be shown:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed`

Here is the Hibernate configuration class:

```
public class ProjectHibernateConfiguration {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ProjectHibernateConfiguration instance;

    private ProjectHibernateConfiguration(String url) {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

            Properties settings = new Properties();
            settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "org.h2.Driver");
            settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:h2:" + url);
            settings.put(Environment.USER, "user");
            settings.put(Environment.PASS, "pass");
            settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
            settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
            settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
            settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
            settings.put(Environment.C3P0_MIN_SIZE, "5");
            settings.put(Environment.C3P0_MAX_SIZE, "20");
            settings.put(Environment.C3P0_TIMEOUT, "1800");


            configuration.setProperties(settings);

            ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                                                                           .build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static void initializeConfiguration(String url) {
        instance = new ProjectHibernateConfiguration(url);
    }

    public static ProjectHibernateConfiguration getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public void closeSessionFactory() {
        this.sessionFactory.close();
    }
```

And the Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProjectHibernateConfiguration.initializeConfiguration("path to a H2 database");
        //Performing some queries to database (no problems)
        ProjectHibernateConfiguration.getInstance().closeSessionFactory();

        ProjectHibernateConfiguration.initializeConfiguration("path to a new H2 database");
        //Performing queries to new initialized database (getting error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed)
    }
}
```

After closing the previous session factory the code does create a new session factory but it seems that something is wrong with creating a new session factory.
So what is wrong with this code?

Comment: you seem to swallow the exception silently with your catch. are you sure second initialization does not throw an exception? please output the stack trace to check this is not the case.

Comment: @feanor07 No exception is thrown during initialization. The `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed` is thrown as soon as the first query is sent to the SessionFactory (actually when calling `sessionFactory.openSession()`).

Comment: there might be another exception being thrown which you might be swallowing. please ensure it is not the case.

Comment: @feanor07 I have checked out & really there is no exception being thrown when initializing the new `SessionFactory`. Is there any logical reason that prevents the programmer to create multiple SessionFactories (closing & opening a new one) during the application lifecycle?